# Postgres: Session duration per event (row)

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query

I'm trying to write a query that builds a session duration per each event.
The database houses events from a webapp, each with a session-id and a timestamp.
Each row represents one event.
I thought I could solve this with a recursive query, but every attempt runs for minutes with no return. It's driving me crazy.
This is what I have so far.

```
with recursive session_time as (
    select
        f.data->'sessionId' as session_id,
        f.ts,
        null::timestamp with time zone as prev_timestamp,
        0 as session_duration
    from arbiter_events as f
    union
    select
        n.data->'sessionId' as session_id,
        n.ts,
        st.ts as prev_timestamp,
        (EXTRACT(epoch from (n.ts - (
            select
                st.ts
            from arbiter_events p
            where p.ts < n.ts
            order by p.ts desc
            limit 1
        ))) + st.session_duration)::integer as session_duration
    from arbiter_events as n
    inner join session_time st on st.session_id = n.data->'sessionId'
)
SELECT
    ae.customer,
    ae.username,
    ae.data->'category' as category,
    ae.data->'subCategory' as subcategory,
    st.session_id,
    st.session_duration
from arbiter_events ae
left join session_time st on ae.data->'sessionId' = st.session_id;
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter looking at you. You've helped me too much through my career so far.

Comment: Why don't you just calculate session_id, MAX(ts) - MIN(ts) ... GROUP BY session_id  ?

Comment: If you're attempting to calculate a running duration, you should be able to use window functions partitioned by session_id ordered by ts.

Comment: You're making this way too complicated.   If your sessionid has integrity then just Group By sessionid and select min(ts) for session start, max(ts) for session end, and max(ts) - min(ts) for elapsed time.  You don't even need window functions  here.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I was overcomplicating this. Trying to optimize a query incorporating `MIN(ts)` now.